# Why is Docker ignoring my container_name stipulation?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I'm running a Docker compose file with one main service and two. sub-services, on which the main service is dependent, as follows:

```sh
docker-compose run -p hlp-api --service-ports web
```

This spins everything up nicely. However, while the sub-services end up with the name I intended, the main service has a name based on the project token (`hlp-api`) I fed in plus an ugly auto-generated appendage.

[image]

Why is the main 'web' service not ending up with the name I specify in its `container_name` param?

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:

  # web service
  web:
    container_name: hlp-api-web
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: /bin/sh -c "gem install bundler && bundle install && rails server --port 3000 --binding 0.0.0.0"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 5432:5432
      - 2222:2222
    volumes:
      - ./webapp:/opt/webapp
      - ../:/app:cached
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
      - rails_cache:/app/tmp/cache
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - ngrok

  # database
  postgres:
    container_name: hlp-api-db
    image: postgres:14.2
    volumes:
      - .psqlrc:/root/.psqlrc:ro
      - dbdat:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./log:/root/log:cached
      - ./latest.dump:/latest.dump
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: hlp-api-dev
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      DB_PORT: 5432
    ports:
      - 5432
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1
      interval: 5s

  # ngrok
  ngrok:
    container_name: hlp-api-ngrok
    image: ngrok/ngrok:latest
    environment:
      - NGROK_AUTHTOKEN
    command: http host.docker.internal:3000

volumes:
  web:
  bundle:
  dbdat:
  node_modules:
  rails_cache:
```

Comment: its by design on run command. You need to use the --name flags to specify a name for this command.

Comment: useing `container_name` is anyway a bad idea, imo. If you care about other things being able to communicate, you can use `--use-aliases`. That way you can talk by service name to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess, for the same reason you have to explicitly use `--service-ports`, they decided that they didn't want name collisions as they didn't wanted to have ports collisions.

If the name would be respected from the `docker compose run` command, that would means that you would always have to specify a name when you want to run the command, if the container is already running, as it will keep on trying to assign the same name over and over again.

The good thing is that you can provide a name, as you can ask it to respect the published ports:

```sh
docker-compose run -p hlp-api --service-ports --name hlp-api-web web
```

Related:

- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2061, and more specifically: [this comment](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2061#issuecomment-140859866)

Answer (score 3):

`docker-compose run` is intended to spin up a one-off container to run a temporary command.  It will start the services the named container `depends_on:`.  It doesn't actually launch the specific container described in the `docker-compose.yml`, but a related container with a different name and a different command.

If you want to actually start the containers listed in the `docker-compose.yml` file, use `docker-compose up`.

A typical use of `docker-compose run` would be to invoke database migrations, for example:

```sh
# Start the entire system
docker-compose up -d

# Start a new temporary container, with the same image and setup
# as the normal Rails container, to run migrations
docker-compose run web \
  bundle exec rails db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason, however, that I'm using `docker compose run` rather than `docker compose up` is that, with the latter, I can't pass in `--service-ports` and without that my app doesn't show up in a browser (for reasons I don't understand.) If there's a way round that, I'll happily use `up`.

Comment: Again, `--service-ports` is specific to `docker-compose run`: since `ports:` usually names a specific host port, you can't `docker-compose run` a temporary container alongside a `docker-compose up` normal container sharing the same host port, so `docker-compose run` disables `ports:`.  `docker-compose up` should publish `ports:` the way you expect without any special options.

Comment: @Mitya your container does not show in your browser because your docker compose overrides the command and your usage of run overrides the override of the command (that becomes complex, is it?), just drop the `command` line in your _docker-compose.yml_ and live happily ever after with `docker compose up`, as David Is suggesting.

Comment: Drop the entire `command` line? But then the gems won't be installed, or the Ruby server started, no? Or do you mean drop just part of it? Incidentally, this command line I got from [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/painless-rails-development-environment-setup-with-docker/), which seems to claim that I need to specify `--port` and `--binding` (though I don't profess to understand it all myself.)

Comment: You should `RUN bundle install` in your Dockerfile, and then it can have `CMD rails server`, and you don't need a Compose `command:`.  You may need to get rid of that entire `volumes:` block too, so the installed gems are in the image and not in named volumes.